# Fine active users

Tags: sql

I have a table that records the user's ID, purchased items and date.

I want to find active users. Active users are users who made a second purchase within 7 days of the first purchase.

For example, if the first purchase is on December 14, 2023, then the period from December 14, 2023 to December 21, 2023 (including these two days) will be regarded as `within 7 days`.

For the example data below, the output results should be `2` and `4`.

| user_id | item | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Laundry Detergent | 2023-11-28 |
| 1 | Gaming Chair | 2023-12-08 |
| 2 | Bed Sheets | 2023-11-15 |
| 2 | Bed Sheets | 2023-11-15 |
| 3 | Coffee Maker | 2023-11-19 |
| 4 | Smart Thermostat | 2023-11-30 |
| 4 | Pressure Cooker | 2023-12-05 |

Outcome:

| user_id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |

I'm using PieCloudDB Database and I have tried the following query, but my outcome is **only user_id 4**, can someone give me a correct answer?

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.user_id
FROM purchase u1
LEFT JOIN purchase u2
ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id AND (DATE_PART('day',u2.date::timestamp - u1.date::timestamp) BETWEEN 0 AND 7) AND u1.item != u2.item
WHERE u2.date is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query filters out purchases of the same item within seven days.

Try my approach in your PieCloudDB database, I divided it into two situations: one is the second purchase made on the same day, and the other is the second purchase made between the second and seventh days.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.user_id
FROM Purchase u1
JOIN
Purchase u2
ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
AND DATE_PART('day',u2.date::timestamp - u1.date::timestamp) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
UNION
SELECT user_id
FROM
Purchase u1
GROUP BY user_id, date
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```